# php upload isset and rename file if it's exist

Tags: php, file-upload

I know, there are many solutions for this question, but unfortunately I couldn't solve it, Here is my upload code:

```
 public static function upload(&$file, $destinationDir = "", $destinationName = "", $secure = true)
  {
$ret = false;

if (isset($file['tmp_name']) && isset($file['name']))
{
  if ($destinationName == '')
  {
    $destinationName = $file['name'];
  }
  $destinationFile = $destinationDir . '/' . $destinationName;

  if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $destinationFile))
  {
    if ($secure)
    {
      chmod($destinationFile, 0644); // without execution permissions if it is possible
    }
    $ret = true;
  }
}

return $ret;
  }
```

1: How can I rename file while uploading to server ?

2: If file name is exist then how to rename it automatically?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use **file_exists** for this case :

```
 public static function upload(&$file, $destinationDir = "", $destinationName = "", $secure = true){
$ret = false;

if(isset($file['tmp_name']) && isset($file['name'])){
  if ($destinationName == ''){
    $destinationName = md5($file['name']);
  }
  $destinationFile = $destinationDir.'/'.$destinationName;

  if(file_exists($destinationFile)){
      // Change the destination file name if it exists
      $destinationFile = $destinationDir.'/'.md5($destinationName.rand());
  }

  if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $destinationFile)){
    if($secure){
      chmod($destinationFile, 0644); // without execution permissions if it is possible
    }
    $ret = true;
  }
}
```

**Note:**
move_uploaded_file — Moves an uploaded file to a new location
structured like this

```
bool move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )
```

in `$destination` parameter you give the name of your new uploaded file. Name your file to something that unique. Whatever !, so don't worry about this

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please tell me how to get path_filename ? Actually the problem now is solved but still path_filename will be saved as real file name not after changed.