# How to avoid upload if file name is exist

Tags: php, file-upload, filepath

First of all, I wanted to use auto rename file , But I couldn't find a solution to get file path name after it's renamed. so, is it possible to add something into my code to check if file exist then it won't allow to upload file?

Here's my code:

```
 public static function upload(&$file, $destinationDir = "", $destinationName = "", $secure = true)
{
$ret = false;

if (isset($file['tmp_name']) && isset($file['name']))
{
  if ($destinationName == '')
  {
    $destinationName = $file['name'];
  }
  $destinationFile = $destinationDir . '/' . $destinationName;

  if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $destinationFile))
  {
  if ($secure)
  {
      chmod($destinationFile, 0644); // without execution permissions if it is possible
  }
    $ret = true;
  }
}

return $ret;
}
```

My problem is about if file exist, it will be replaced to existing file, I could find a way to use auto renamed file, something like this:

```
$ext = pathinfo($file["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$destinationName = sha1_file($file["tmp_name"]).time().".".$ext;
```

However I couldn't find a solution to post file name after renamed into sql table. It will post as real name not renamed file.

So my last choice is to add something into my code to check if file exist then avoid to upload file if its exist.

Could you please help me on this issue?

Thank you so much

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php appropriately enough.

Comment: strangely enough http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256209/php-upload-isset-and-rename-file-if-its-exist contains the same code you're using, with an answer in there.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256209/php-upload-isset-and-rename-file-if-its-exist

Comment: those codes didn't  work for me, that's why I couldn't find a solution, I had to ask again to solve my problem.

Comment: describe "didn't work". I can't see how that would fail. If your form doesn't contain the right parts to get it off the ground, then that could be why. Hard to say here. check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting function (T_FUNCTION        and     PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC)

Comment: those above syntax errors I got, thats why I mentioned "didn't work"

Comment: you'll need to restructure your conditional statements. There are many scripts out there that will do what you want to achieve and many that may lead you back to Q&A's here on Stack.

Comment: public static function sendMail($from, $fromName, $to, $toName, $subject, $text, $html, $attachFiles = null)

Answer (score 0):

Using your code suggestion, maybe something like this:

Under this line: $destinationFile = $destinationDir . '/' . $destinationName;

Put this:

```
if(file_exists($destinationFile)){
    $ext = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $destinationFile = $destinationDir.'/'.sha1_file($file['tmp_name']).time().'.'.$ext;
}
```